# Finding areas of regions determined by a rectangle overlapping an annulus

Tags: geometry

[image: Drawing of the question]

So I've been trying to find the areas of DBCF, CFK and ABD as seen on the picture for a research project I'm doing. The start point were r, h and hmiddle. I've done some work and you can see some of it in the picture, but am unsure how to continue. Anyone has suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You have

$$ OD = OB = r-h $$
$$ AD = CK = \frac{h_m}{2} $$

Then, using Pythagorean on $\triangle OAD$

$$ OA = \sqrt{OD^2-AD^2} = \sqrt{(r-h)^2-\frac{h_m^2}{4}} $$

The angle is found by

$$ \phi = \angle AOD = \sin^{-1} \frac{AD}{OD} = \sin^{-1}\left(\frac{h_m}{2(r-h)}\right) $$

You now have enough information to compute the areas of the circular wedge $OBD$ and the triangle $\triangle OAD$. The area of the curved piece $ABD$ is the difference of these two areas, i.e.

$$ S_{ABD} = \frac{OB^2\cdot \phi}{2} - \frac{OA\cdot AD}{2} $$

This is where numerical values are useful.

---

The remaining areas are a bit more involved. You'll first need to construct a point $M$ on $OC$ such that $CKFM$ is a rectangle, i.e. $MC = FK$. **Edit:** To find $MC$, first find $OM$ from the right triangle $OFM$, i.e.

$$ OM = \sqrt{OF^2-FM^2} = \sqrt{r^2-\frac{h_m^2}{4}} $$

You can use the same trick to find the area of the curved piece $MFC$ using the radius $OC = r$. Then the area of $CFK$ can be subtracted, i.e. $S_{CFK} = S_{CKFM} - S_{MFC}$

---

Finally, subtract the two areas you just found from the rectangle $ACKD$ to find the area of $BCFD$. This should be simple enough when you know $AC = OC - OA$

Comment: Thanks for the help, I think I understood everything you said, the one issue I still see is how to find FK (MC)?

Comment: I added some more to the answer. Basically, you'll need to find the area of the triangle $OFM$ by finding $OM$, then $MC = OC-OM$

Answer (score 0):

I find $hmiddle$ is confusing notation when you have another $h$.  Let's call it $m$ instead

Then I believe

- $OC=OR=OF=r$
- $BC= DR=h $
- $OB=OD=r-h$
- $CK=AD= \frac{m}{2}$
- $OA = \sqrt{(r-h)^2 - \left(\frac{m}{2}\right)^2}$
- $AB = r-h - \sqrt{(r-h)^2 - \left(\frac{m}{2}\right)^2}$
- $AC = DK = r - \sqrt{(r-h)^2 - \left(\frac{m}{2}\right)^2}$
- $DF =  \sqrt{r^2 - \left(\frac{m}{2}\right)^2} - \sqrt{(r-h)^2 - \left(\frac{m}{2}\right)^2} $
- $FK = r - \sqrt{r^2 - \left(\frac{m}{2}\right)^2}$

making the areas of the triangles

- $\triangle CFK = \frac m4 \left(r - \sqrt{r^2 - \left(\frac{m}{2}\right)^2} \right)$
- $\triangle ABD = \frac m4 \left(r-h - \sqrt{(r-h)^2 - \left(\frac{m}{2}\right)^2} \right)$

And I believe the area of the quadrilateral

- $DBCF = DACK -\triangle CFK- \triangle ABD = \frac m4 \left(h  + \sqrt{r^2 - \left(\frac{m}{2}\right)^2} - \sqrt{(r-h)^2 - \left(\frac{m}{2}\right)^2} \right) $

Comment: I don't think the question is about the triangles, but rather the curved areas where $BD$ and $CF$ are two circular arcs

Comment: @Dylan - You may be correct, rereading the question makes it unclear to me

Comment: It is a bit ambiguous. I also thought that the first time.